# Highcharts stock data grouping not working properly without groupPixelWidth

Tags: highcharts

I cannot get Highchart stock to properly group my data according to my units with a line chart (xAxis type is 'datetime'). Here's my settings:

```
series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: true,
            forced: true,
            groupAll: true,
            approximation: 'sum',
            units: [
                ['minute', [5, 15, 30]],
                ['hour', [1]],
                ['day', [1]],
            ],
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                minute: ['%A %e %b, %H:%M', '%A %e %b, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
                hour: ['%A %e %b, %H:%M', '%A %e %b, %H:%M', '-%H:%M'],
                day: ['%A %e %b, %Y', '%A %e %b', '%A %e %b, %Y'],
            }
        },
        }
```

I expect the data to be grouped by days when the chart first loads. But the data are actually grouped according to my minimum unit (5 minutes). I can get it to work if I add `groupPixelWidth: 100`, but that's quite arbitrary and I'm afraid the user experience will change on different screen sizes (moreover, my chart container width is dynamic). Does someone knows a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you well, but would you like to display the data only day by day? If yes,  you can achieve it by defining just the `day` in units, demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c36ryqef/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel I'd like to display by days if it's appropriate, and then by hours and minutes when zooming. If I don't set groupPixelWidth it always displays by 5 minutes no matter what.

Comment: May I see a demo with the sample of your data?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel [There you go](https://jsfiddle.net/rnp675gL/1/). You'll see that no grouping by day occur without groupPixelWidth set.

Comment: I think that using `groupPixelWidth` is a solution to your case. Notice that if you zoom your chart very much finally you get the data grouped by minutes no matter what the chart plot width is. Of course the 'deepest of zooming' will be different on different containers width, but the final output is the same. I don't think that there is any other way... Maybe using the `responsive` options and change the `groupPixelWidth` to a lower value for different container width helps: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/responsive

Comment: I guess I'll have to dynamically calculate `groupPixelWidth` based on my container's width and the total number of points to be displayed.  Quite frustrating. Thanks anyway @SebastianWędzel